# How can I fix flow server error on windows? crashes with wierd error message

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, flowtype

I am trying to use Flow-Type in a react native project by using npm package flow-bin. but when I try to run flow, it gives an error `Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ENOTSOCK, "select", "")`. I have been looking for a solution but no luck so far. Following are the details of the error. Plus; I have tried to completely uninstall nodejs and installed it again but still the same result.

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

```
node --version
v15.9.0
```

```
npm --version
7.5.3
```

```
Operating System
Windows 10 Pro 64bit
Build 20H2
```

**Steps to Error**

```
npm init
npm i -D flow-bin
add flow to script in package.json
npm run flow init
npm run flow

ERROR
```

**Error Details**

[PowerShell Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqHaK.png)

**Logs**

```
[2021-02-24 03:44:28.921] argv=E:\LearningLab\Work\TechnicianApp\node_modules\flow-bin\flow-win64-v0.135.0\flow.exe start --flowconfig-name .flowconfig --temp-dir C:\Users\ajplu\AppData\Local\Temp\flow E:\LearningLab\Work\TechnicianApp
[2021-02-24 03:44:28.921] lazy_mode=off
[2021-02-24 03:44:28.921] arch=types_first
[2021-02-24 03:44:28.921] abstract_locations=off
[2021-02-24 03:44:28.921] max_workers=4
[2021-02-24 03:44:28.921] debug=false
[2021-02-24 03:44:28.922] Initializing Server (This might take some time)
[2021-02-24 03:44:28.922] executable=E:\LearningLab\Work\TechnicianApp\node_modules\flow-bin\flow-win64-v0.135.0\flow.exe
[2021-02-24 03:44:28.923] version=0.135.0
[2021-02-24 03:44:28.923] No saved state available
[2021-02-24 03:44:28.924] Parsing
Monitor died unexpectedly
```

**Monitor Logs**

```
Feb 24 03:44:28.796 [info] argv=E:\LearningLab\Work\TechnicianApp\node_modules\flow-bin\flow-win64-v0.135.0\flow.exe start --flowconfig-name .flowconfig --temp-dir C:\Users\ajplu\AppData\Local\Temp\flow E:\LearningLab\Work\TechnicianApp
Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ENOTSOCK, "select", "")
Raised by primitive operation at file "src/common/lwt/lwtInit.ml", line 36, characters 18-46
Called from file "list.ml", line 117, characters 24-34
Called from file "src/common/lwt/lwtInit.ml", line 34, characters 8-206
Called from file "src/unix/lwt_engine.ml", line 344, characters 8-19
Called from file "src/unix/lwt_main.ml", line 33, characters 4-78
Called from file "src/common/lwt/lwtInit.ml", line 129, characters 4-135
Called from file "src/hack_forked/utils/sys/daemon.ml", line 150, characters 4-20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this reason.

It turned out somehow Astril VPN was causing flow server to crash. even though it was only installed and not running. After uninstalling Astril flow works like a charm.

If someone encounters a similar problem, then they should try to uninstall their VPN/Proxy software. I am not sure if other VPN software can cause this issue because I have only used Astril.